# Which events were overwritten in The Flash?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In *The Flash* season 2 episode 17:

> Barry goes back in time to get help from Eobard Thawne on how to get faster, to aid in stopping Zoom, but while going back a time wraith tries to stop Barry, altering the timeline. While trying to repair the timeline, the wraith attacks Barry again and starts to kill him, only to be stopped when Hartley kills it. Hartley, being a villain in Barry's timeline, appears to have turned good.

Furthermore, Caitlin says:

> Ever since Evil Wells got erased from existence, no one speaks Latin around here anymore.

Which events were altered, and which never happened?
Was there a firestorm? Singularity opening? Earth 2? Did Barry go back in time to save his mom?

Did all the events in season 1 and 2 get overwritten?

Comment: There. It's rudimentary and takes a few points out of your original (I don't want it to seem like each of those examples was a question in its own right, though you should probably ask them separately for extra points, rather than all together). Try to keep it concise; while group answers are possible, typically questions that ask multiple questions get closed.

Comment: I dint know you see it sorry

Comment: Everyone sees it when you don't put things behind spoiler tags.

Comment: Voting to close based on our [future works policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/5184). All we can do right now is speculate based on 2 minutes of show that took place after the time travel.

Answer (score 6):

Most of Season 1 happened as we observed last year. The biggest change was that

> Hartley Rathaway never attacked the Cleveland Dam and instead started working with Team Flash after saving Cisco and Caitlyn from a time wraith

We know that several things *did* still occur though:

#### Eobard Thawne

The final confrontation in Season 1 plays out in a very similar way. During the one on one in the time vault, Barry gives Eobard a disjointed version of events to come. This results in Eobard thinking he makes it back home.

> Eobard: I haven't beaten you. If you're still alive... that means my plan fails. And if my plan fails, I don't get to go home, and if that's the case, well, then... [begins vibrating hand]
>  Barry: No, no, no! Hey, hey, hey! It's the opposite! It's the opposite! It... you trick me. You harness my speed. We turn on the accelerator to create a path for you to go home. I go back in time. You go back to yours. You won.
>  Eobard: Then why are you here?
>  Barry: Because when I got back, a singularity had formed. And now the only way for me to learn how to get faster and stop the singularity from happening was to come here. Now.
>  Eobard: Well, that's good to know.

This is a combination of what Earth-2 Wells does with regard to the Zoom plot line. He

> steals some of Barry's speed

This also references of the younger version of Eobard we meet in Season 2. The Wells/Eobard that Barry is speaking with should remember this, but Barry is cryptic enough that it may not seem like the same incident:

> Flash and Reverse Flash run through the pipeline until Flash tosses Thawne through portal back to his own time.

Finally, Barry mentions that he goes back in time. He has done this multiple times, both intentionally and unintentionally:

> The first time prevents a tidal wave from hitting Central City (this was accidental)
>  The second is the trip back to watch his mother die (this was intentional) - the singularity also forms shortly after this trip
>  The third is when team Arrow helps fight Vandal Savage and the loss destroys the city (this was accidental)
>  The fourth is the current time travel trip he's on (this was intentional)

#### Eddie Thawne

We know that Eddie still dies based on the final scene in this episode. We also know that the death is in the same fashion as before. Eddie's death "erases" Eobard's existance.

> Hartley: [says something in Latin]
>  Caitlyn: How many times do we have to tell you, Hartley? Ever since Evil Wells got erased from existence, no one speaks Latin around here anymore.

Then even later:

> Iris: It's been almost a year already. Can you believe that? 
>  Barry: That's the thing, Iris. Everything keeps moving forward. Question is, when will you? 
>  Iris: I don't know, Barry.

#### Firestorm and Earth 2 and Zoom

These three plot lines are all linked together. We know that Earth 2 still exists and that Barry has interacted with it. After returning to his time, Barry talks with Earth 2 Wells:

> Wells: Yeah, I'm okay. Although it turns out it's easier to find a two-ton gorilla on this earth than a teenage daughter. I don't know what I've done.
>  Barry: You did what you thought you had to do. You risked your life to save her. You brought her here to protect her from Zoom. You acted like a father.

This confirms that Earth 2 and Zoom still exist. Firestorm is linked to this plot line because

> Ronnie's sacrifice is what destroyed the singularity.

Without that action, the singularity would have destroyed Central City.

---

So, what did change? This adventure did change some aspects of the time line

#### Hartley

After returning to the present and encountering the time wraith there

> Cisco's weapon is ineffective. It is Hartley's gloves that save Barry.

We then learn that this isn't a one time deal and that he's reconciled with his parents.

> Hartley: Well, as always, it's been a pleasure working with you all on this little project. If you need anything in the future, call me. I'm off to a late dinner. 
>  Cisco: Mm, dinner. Anyone special? 
>  Hartley: Very. My parents.

He is also aware of the Flash's identity (though, to be fair...many people on the show are).

#### Team Flash

Cisco and Caitlyn spent a year working on a weapon to fight the time wraith.

#### Flash

There appears to be two distinct ways of time traveling on The Flash. The first is accidental and when this occurs, he merges with his past self. This results in only a single "Flash" at that point in time. The other is intentional and this results in two Flashes that can (and do) interact with one another. In this instance, it was intentional and the two Flashes interact on multiple occassions. The result of this is that one version of the Flash remembers a time when

> Cleveland Dam was attacked

and the other remembers

> Being attacked by a future version of himself and then working with that version. This version also remembers Hartley as an ally

How this plays out is yet to be seen, but there are two distinct timelines with regard to this aspect of the Flash's past year.

Comment: This is a better explanation  thank you

Comment: How did you know all this

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, everything we know from Season 1 still occurred, with the following changes in the timeline:

- Eobard Thawne now has every reason to believe he will successfully make it home
- Eddie Thawne recorded a video for Iris onto future Barry's phone
- Instead of escaping his cell, The Pied Piper became a hero after his single failed attempt at being a villain, thus getting back into his parent's good graces and becoming an ally of Team Flash
- Team Flash now remembers an incident where future Barry came back and did these things before returning to the future.

Comment: so all of this still happens firestorm  singularaty openning  earth 2 and meeting jay garrick and patty  barry knowing about reverse flash thawne  his dad getting out of prison and fighting zoom  eboard thawne going home to the future and him being erased from existince and barry going back in time to save is mom and say his last goodbyes and meeting his doppelganger on earth 2 but no fighting hartley at the dam and no transporting metahumans and stopping savage

Comment: Wow, that's hard to read, but yes - as I understand it all other events still happen as we originally witnessed on the show.

Comment: but how hartley never escaped and no news about the acelerator and no fight at the dam

Comment: how come everything that happend after episode 11 of season 1 and everything that happened during season 1 and 2 still happened but the events of episode 11 of season 1 were changed

Comment: @AndrewCasali: because... that’s what the writers wrote? It’s not like we have real-life incidents of time travel to compare it to. Perhaps you could explain more specifically what doesn’t make sense to you?

Comment: how did everything that happend in season 1 2 up to season 2 episode 17 after season 1 epiosde 11 still happend even though the events of episode 11 of season 1 were changed

Comment: @AndrewCasali: I'm sorry to see that the Shift key and all the keys for punctuation characters on your keyboard are broken.  If you're using Windows, you can use a neat program called `osk` (On-Screen Keyboard) to enter periods, commas, and capital letters by using the mouse.